# How to load numpy sparse array containing TFIDF from scikit into Kmeans

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, pickle, tf-idf

I have the following code. I have trained TFIDF using scikit vectorizer

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

count_vectorizer = CountVectorizer(min_df=1,stop_words="english")
term_freq_matrix = count_vectorizer.fit_transform(vectoriser.mydoclist)
# print "Vocabulary:", count_vectorizer.vocabulary_

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer

tfidf = TfidfTransformer(norm="l2")
tfidf.fit(term_freq_matrix)

tf_idf_matrix = tfidf.transform(term_freq_matrix)
print len(count_vectorizer.get_feature_names())
# for term in count_vectorizer.get_feature_names(): 
    # [k for k in count_vectorizer.get_feature_names() if '#' in k]:
    # if '#' in term:
    # print term.encode('utf-8')
# print np.matrix(tf_idf_matrix.todense())
# np.savetxt("foo.csv", (np.matrix(tf_idf_matrix.todense())), delimiter=",")
# np.savetxt("foo.csv", tf_idf_matrix.toarray(),fmt="%.4e")

# with open("foo-c.csv","w") as outputFile:

# np.save("pick",np.array(tf_idf_matrix))
# np.savez("pick",data = tf_idf_matrix.data ,indices=tf_idf_matrix.indices,indptr =tf_idf_matrix.indptr, shape=tf_idf_matrix.shape )
```

I want to store it in a fashion which is fast and efficient . I have tried csv but the data goes in 20 gb . I cant load the csr matrix from pick file .I am getting error for K means algo saying the sequence provided .

Can anyone help me to load this csr matrix into K means for scikit

Comment: "I am getting error for K means algo saying the sequence provided ." Can you show the code you tried and the exact Error message ?

Comment: K means `fit()` method supports sparse matrices. So unless you show the code in which you are getting error, and some samples of data, we are unable to help

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the `tf_idf_matrix` is a `scipy.sparse` `csr_matrix`, the `savez` line looks fine.  But you'll have to reconstruct the matrix from those saved arrays (with `sparse` or `tf` code).

Sparse matrices don't have a pickle method, so the `np.save` approach won't work.

```
In [172]: np.array(As)
Out[172]: 
array(<1000x1000 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 1000 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>, dtype=object)
```

With an array like this `np.save` tries to use `pickle` for the object.

Does `sklearn` provide any sparse save methods?  `scipy` has a couple save methods that can handle sparse matrices.  The one I've use the MATLAB compatible `loadmat/savemat`.